# More fun with "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I have tried to post the following to Stack Overflow:

---

> I have a very simple HTML form embedded in an email I send to people who have subscribed to my blog so they can confirm their email addresses. The embedded code is:
>
> $_POST['Name_First'],
> Thank you for subscribing to my Blog.
>
> Please click  to confirm your email address.
> Thank you!
>
> P. James Norris
> Order Cetacea
>
> where the two PHP variables are supplied by the PHP of my blog page that sends the email.
>
> What appears in the sent email is what I would expect:
>
> > P. James,
> >
> > Thank you for subscribing to my Blog.
> >
> > Please click here to confirm your email address.
> >
> > Thank you!
> >
> > P. James Norris
> >
> > Order Cetacea
> >
> > Sent from [www.ocetacea.net/pjamesnorris](http://www.ocetacea.net/pjamesnorris)
>
> where the "here" appears as a hyperlink.
>
> When I click on the link (having subscribed myself with one of my email addresses), [my blog](https://www.ocetacea.net/pjamesnorris/blog-work.php) page loads but does not appear to receive the email address as `POST` data (or `GET` data, for that matter)--I `echo` both but nothing appears on the page.
>
> I built a webpage using exactly the same code as the email, and clicking on "here" on the webpage works as I want the email form to work, *i.e.*, the email address is transmitted to my blog page as `POST` data.
>
> I've looked at [Adding HTML forms to...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316715/adding-html-forms-to-email) and [Embed HTML form in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920797/embed-html-form-in-email) and both of these posts are quite old and, I hope, quite out of date.
>
> Could someone please tell me what obvious and stupid mistake I'm making?
>
> Thanks.

---

And I got the error message:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

And I cannot figure out why.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Three backticks are only for code *blocks*. For inline code, use a single backtick. I'm not sure if this is what's causing the problem or not, but other than this, everything you posted here looks perfectly fine, so it's worth a try.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Inline code is delimited by an arbitrary number of backticks. However the current SO software does not handle inline backticks correctly. See the CommonMark spec.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike I tried one back-tick and that didn't display the inline code as inline. To make it render as inline code, I had to use four white-spaces.

Comment: @philipxy can you provide a link to the "CommonMark spec"?

Comment: If the system thinks that my post "appears to contain code..." why doesn't it just tell what the suspicious/problematic code is?

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#code-spans (see link at https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: **To close voters:** this question is *not* specific to Stack Overflow only. The code filter mentioned in this question is enabled on **multiple sites on the network**, not just Stack Overflow. This question can be equally applied to other sites with the same filter.

Comment: There are six trailing spaces in it (which doesn't appear to come from the HTML). Though that isn't expected to cause problems. The HTML part is 623 characters.

Comment: Re *"why doesn't it just tell what the suspicious/problematic code is?"*: Indeed. It is an illness of modern software to only provide generic and unspecific error messages (essentially *"An error occurred"* and nothing else), even if the software has the information.